# Page reload upon filter selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter, reload

My problem is that my script is not working upon a user selects a filter. Before that the "Show More" and "Show Less" buttons are perfectly working. Upon selecting a filter, they don't anymore and the script won't even load. Upon page refresh, the script is working again ONLY UNTIL selecting a filter again.

Just a quick brief: We're on a collection page and on the filter sidebar. We're displaying the first 6 options and the "Show More" button in default state. Upon clicking on "Show More" all filters are unhided. (the 'hide' class is removed from them, which is styled with CSS to 'display: none').

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
<div id ="less-button" class="show-less-button-{{ forloop.index }}">
  <button id="btnfilter-{{ forloop.index }}" type="button" class="show-more-filters">Show Less</button>
</div>
<div id="more-button" class="show-more-button-{{ forloop.index }}">
  <button id="btnfilter-{{ forloop.index }}" type="button" class="show-more-filters">Show More</button>
</div>
```

And here is the script I'm using for the filter "Show More" and "Show Less" button:

```
    HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function(cls) {
    var i;
    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] == cls) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};


{% comment %} This is for the Size filters {% endcomment %}
  const parent_size = document.getElementsByClassName("Size");
  const children_size = parent_size[1].children;
  const morebutton_size = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more-button-2")
  const lessbutton_size = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-button-2")

  for(i = 6; i < children_size.length-1; i++) {
    children_size[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
  
  morebutton_size[1].addEventListener("click", function filterunhide(){
    for(i = 6; i < children_size.length-1; i++){
      if(children_size[i].hasClass('hide')){
        children_size[i].classList.remove('hide');
      }
    }
     morebutton_size[1].classList.add('hide')
  });
  lessbutton_size[1].addEventListener("click", function filterhide(){
    for(i = 6; i < children_size.length-1; i++){
      children_size[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
     morebutton_size[1].classList.remove('hide')
  })

{% comment %} This is for the Marca filters {% endcomment %}
  const parent_marca = document.getElementsByClassName("Marca");
  const children_marca = parent_marca[1].children;
  const morebutton_marca = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more-button-3")
  const lessbutton_marca = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-button-3")

  for(i = 6; i < children_marca.length-1; i++) {
    children_marca[i].classList.add("hide");
  }
  
  morebutton_marca[1].addEventListener("click", function filterunhide(){
    for(i = 6; i < children_marca.length-1; i++){
      if(children_marca[i].hasClass('hide')){
        children_marca[i].classList.remove('hide');
      }
    }
     morebutton_marca[1].classList.add('hide')
  });
  lessbutton_marca[1].addEventListener("click", function filterhide(){
    for(i = 6; i < children_marca.length-1; i++){
      children_marca[i].classList.add('hide');
    }
     morebutton_marca[1].classList.remove('hide')
  })
```

I've tried adding Event listener to the "Linklist__Item" class elements, which are the filters, with a click function to reload the page. This was a half solution, because it selected the filter AND refreshed the page BUT the filter selection wasn't stored in the data, so basically the filter was not selected.

What's happening atm is when I change the filters, an page refresh is happening and updating the filters using jquery Ajax BUT this is not truly reloading the page, only refresh the content.

Hopefully someone can help figure the problem out.

Comment: Not being critical here, but that is a lot of code for anyone on here to look at and I wasn't able to fully follow what you were describing. But I would suggest adding some console.log() statements and get a feel for what is happening in your code. You say some buttons stop working after selecting something the 1st time. So add some console.log() statements (adding debugger; works too) around the code that handles  the show more/less button clicks. Are they even being executed? Then go from there if that makes sense.

Comment: The show more/less buttons are being executed if a user doesn't select any filters. Upon selecting one however, the script is not working anymore.

Comment: I'm agree with @Andrew. By the way, what's in the console now? Probably in there can be an error message so the script stops